# What is the state of exception safety in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I know about the with statement for Python resource handling. What other concerns are there for exception safe code in Python?

EDIT: The concern here is with opening files and such. For instance, suppose an init function raises an exception. What is the state of the object being initialized?

Comment: Umm, what are you talking about? Safety of what? This seems like it's a pretty broad topic. What's your question?

Comment: The object already exists before `__init__()` is called -- that's what the first argument, usually called `self` is -- but it's not yet initialized. If an exception occurs during that process it may end up only partially or even completely uninitialized, depending on how the exception gets handled and by what.

Comment: Here's what I meant about an object not being initialized properly depending on how an exception occurring in the `__init__()` method was handled: ![example code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/__init__exception.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For instance, suppose an init function raises an exception. What is the state of the object being initialized?

Hint.  When in doubt, actually run an experiment.

```
>>> class Partial( object ):
...     def __init__( self ):
...         self.a= 1
...         raise Exception
...         self.b= 2
... 
>>> p= Partial()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
Exception
>>> p
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

The statement -- as a whole -- fails.  Object not created.  Variable not assigned.
Any other questions?

In C++, things are so much more complex.  In Python, the object is simply discarded.

Comment: If everyone did an experiment when in doubt we'd have like 90% less Python questions on SO -- that is very good advice :-)

Comment: @THC4k often just trying something that someone is asking about and posting the results makes for a solid answer. Sshhh... don't tell everyone...

Comment: @THC4k On the other hand it is good to ask as you get deeper knowledge than just by experiment.

Comment: @S.Lott, I think that the object is actually created but it isn't returned. Consider what will happen if you add self to global collection just before the exception is raised.

Comment: @Piotr Czapla: "I think that the object is actually created but it isn't returned".  Yes and no.  Your example of doing some global side-effect in `__init__` is not a general answer.  It's what happens when there's a contrived, hidden global side-effect in `__init__`.  The general answer is that the object initialization raises an exception and the statement doesn't complete execution.

Comment: @Piotr Czapla: "it is good to ask as you get deeper knowledge".  False.  You get someone else's incomplete information.  You **only** learn by doing.

Comment: @S.Lott The fact that the object is created can have impact not only on badly designed code. If you writing a kind of finalizer (`__del__` in python). It is a really rare case but it happens.

Comment: @S.Lott btw. Do you always work with good code?

Comment: This example does NOT show Strong Exception Safety (which I think OP was actually asking for, their edit to ask about constructor led people astray..) properly, because object creation itself in many languages can't throw an exception and just fails(Java for example). S.E.S. would require -regular- method failure not effecting system state. I don't know the 'right' answer for python(hence why I googled this question), but this isn't it.

Answer (score 3):

If you asking about language constructs:

- Use `try: except: else:` it ensures that you won't catch wrong exceptions.
- Think twice before you catch `BaseException`, `Exception` or use bare `except:` 
  as you can easly catch to much:

  - your spelling errors - NameError, ImportError
  - user's attempt to terminate your program. KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit
  - errors that indicates incomplete implementation: NotImplementedError
- If you decide to catch generic exceptions log them using `log.exception('your message', e)`
- Keep in mind that exceptions in python are used also for regular flow control (like `StopIteration` exception)
- Use new syntax: `except MyException as myex:` instead of `except MyException, myex:`. It is easier to read for not experienced python developers.

Here is an example that catches NameError:

```
try:
   this_doesn_not_exisit();
except Exception: #Don't do that!
   pass

print "But this line is still printed"
```

**Answer to the edited question:**

- Regarding files if you read text files always use codecs.open instead of open to ensure that you can safety store unicode strings.
- Regarding the `__init__` and state of the object. `__init__` is an initializer so the object already exist when `__init__` is called. If you raise an exception the flow will be interrupted and object won't get stored in any variable so it will be garbage collected. At least that is my understanding. Think that MyObject() is just a function that returns a value if you raise an exception you return nothing, the flow is interrupted and the value you were assigning to isn't modified.

Check this out:

```
>>> def throw(): raise Exception() 
... 
>>> a=1
>>> a=throw()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in throw
Exception
>>> a
1
```

Here is an example to prove that the object is created even if you raise exception in `__init__`. I wasn't able to post that fragment in the comments to @S.Lott answer:

```
 >>> global_collection=[]
 >>> class Partial(object):
 ...    def __init__(self):
 ...       self.test="test"
 ...       global_collection.append(self)
 ...       raise Exception()
 ...
 >>> x=Partial()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
 Exception
 >>> global_collection
 [<__main__.Partial object at 0xb74f8f6c>]
 >>> global_collection[0].test
 'test'
```

**UPDATE:**
Included comments made by: @Paul McGuire, @martineau, @aaronasterling

Comment: I'd include finally with your try: except: else:.  The finally clause works great for ensuring that files are closed, resources are freed, regardless of what errors popped up (which are temp saved).  http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#try

Comment: FWIW, you can't actually catch a syntax error. That error occurs before your program is compiled and running so your `try` statement isn't executing at the time.

Comment: There is no syntax error in your first example -- `this_doesn_not_exisit();` is fine syntactically. There is however a `NameError` exception occurring, which is because there's nothing named `this_doesn_not_exisit`. As Aaron explained, no `except`, even a generic one, can catch a `SyntaxError` (but I think your advice not to use that kind is otherwise generally valid).

Comment: "Never catch generic Exception" should read "Never use bare `catch:` clause."  Exceptions have been refactored so that exceptions like KeyboardInterrupt do not derive from Exception, but from Exception's superclass, BaseException.  `catch Exception:` is perfectly acceptable as a catch-all clause, without the problems of `catch:`.

Comment: @marteau, @aaronasterling - Good point it seams I said syntax when I though semantic error. I guess the only way you can catch syntax error is when using eval. (which should be avoided anyway)

Comment: @Piotr Czapla: "the object is created".  While true, it's a useless technical tidbit, except in the contrived case of a hidden global side-effect in `__init__`.  These are rare and generally a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Python isn't like C++. Exceptions produce useful backtraces. If you're taking user input, catch appropriate exceptions (like `EOFError`) but otherwise, you don't have to do anything special to be exception safe. If a program does something unexpected and throws an exception, use the resulting stack dump to debug your problem. If you're going for extremely high availability, you might want to wrap your top level with a `try/except` in a loop with a log and restart.

Comment: Strong Exception Safety doesn't have anything to do with backtraces, etc. It has to do if the system is in a consistent state if an exception is raised. Unless Python does everything inside a java-like 'try' block and then applies all the changes... meaning that none of the changes to the state are applied unless there is no exceptions, then python itself is not inherently S.E.S. Yes, S.E.S. in C++ is hard to do too. but it isn't limited just being able 'catch' exceptions.